# Como puedo hacer Cascading DropDownListFor en ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tengo un proyecto ASP.NET MVC sin entity Framework y tengo una view para agregar Clientes, pero al agregar un nuevo cliente, utilizo al llenar los campos 2 **`DropDownList`** (uno de Tipo de producto y el otro de Producto) que ya se llenan con información.

Lo que quiero hacer es que si elijo un tipo de producto, el segundo **`DropDownListFor`** despliegue solamente productos que tengan ese Tipo de productos. les anexo el código para ver si me pueden ayudar.

Este es el **controller**

```
        public ActionResult Create()
        {

            ClienteDBHanndle tpd = new ClienteDBHanndle();
            List<SelectListItem> ListaProductos = new List<SelectListItem>();
            var productos = tpd.GetProductos();
            foreach (var item in productos)
            {
                ListaProductos.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item.Nombre, Value = item.IDProducto.ToString() });
            }
            ViewBag.ListaProductos = ListaProductos;


            var tipoproductos = tpd.GetTProductos();
            List<SelectListItem> ListaTipoProductos = new List<SelectListItem>();
            foreach (var item in tipoproductos)
            {
                ListaTipoProductos.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item.Nombre, Value = item.IDTipoProducto.ToString() });
            }
            ViewBag.ListaTipoProductos = ListaTipoProductos;

            return View();
        }
```

Estos son los 2 **DropDownList**

```
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IDTipoProducto, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ListaTipoProductos, "Selecciona tipo de producto", new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IDTipoProducto, "", new {@id = "IDTipoProducto", @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IDproducto, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IDproducto, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ListaProductos, "Selecciona tipo de producto", new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IDproducto, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

Este es el **model**

```
namespace CTEMVC.ViewModel
{
    public class ClientesViewModel
    {

        public int IDCliente { get; set; }

        public int IDTipoProducto { get; set; }

        public int IDproducto { get; set; }

        public string Nombre { get; set; }

        public int Clave { get; set; }

        public int DiasCredito { get; set; }

        public string Calle { get; set; }

        public string Colonia { get; set; }

        public string RFC { get; set; }

        public string Estado { get; set; }

        public string Pais { get; set; }

        public short Activo { get; set; }

        public string NombreProducto { get; set; }



    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para realizar un **Cascading DropDownList** de la forma que preguntas, necesitas utilizar **jQuery**, y más en concreto las funcionalidades **AJAX**.

En principio necesitas crear una Acción en tu Controlador, que devuelva en formato JSON los productos de un determinado tipo de producto:

```
    public JsonResult GetProductosList(int IDTipoProducto)
    {            
        var tipoproductos = tpd.GetTProductos(IDTipoProducto);
        return Json(tipoproductos, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Por otra parte, debes definir en tu Vista un **Script jQuery**, que llame mediante AJAX a la Acción  `GetProductosList(int IDTipoProducto)` cada vez que se seleccione un elemento en el `DropDownList` `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IDTipoProducto`.

El código sería algo así:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#IDTipoProducto").change(function () {
            $.get("/Home/GetProductosList", { IDTipoProducto: $("#IDTipoProducto").val() }, function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                    $("#IDproducto").append("<option value='" + row.IDproducto + "'>" + row.NombreProducto  + "</option>")
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

> **Nota**: Para una información más completa acerca de cómo crear un Cascading DropDownList en ASP.NET MVC, te recomiendo leas
>   detenidamente este artículo: [Cómo crear un Cascading DropDownList en
>   ASP.NET MVC](http://www.rafaelacosta.net/Blog/2019/11/24/c%C3%B3mo-crear-un-cascading-dropdownlist-en-aspnet-mvc)

Comment: exactamente hice esto que me recomendaste y funciono, muchas gracias